# No logro que cargue mi imagen en el canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estaba creando un blog de prueba mientras aprendía programación web. ¿Por qué no carga? Es sobre café y esas cosas. El canvas es de 1366x120 pero la imagen es de 2000x2000. No sé si tenga que editar la imagen.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('banner');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

var bannerHeader={
  url:"bannerCafe.jpg",
  cargaOK:false
}
bannerHeader.imagen=new Image();
bannerHeader.imagen.src=bannerHeader.url;
bannerHeader.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarBanner());

function cargarBanner()
  {
    bannerHeader.cargaOK=true;
    dibujar()
  }
function dibujar()
{
  if(bannerHeader.cargaOK=true)
  {ctx.drawImage(bannerHeader.imagen,0,0)}
}
```

```html
<canvas id="banner" width="1366" height="130"></canvas>
<script src="imagenes.js"></script>
```

Comment: cual es la ruta correcta de la imagen?

Comment: @simon Está en la mismo carpeta. ¿Es necesario especificar la ruta completa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno creo que estas creando muchas funciones innecesarias para crear una imagen en un canvas por ejemplo yo si quisiera agregar una imagen hiciera lo siguiente:

una funcion la cual selecciona el div por ejemplo de esta manera: *document.getElementById* despues creo un objecto el cual te ayudaria a  traerlo de una manera facil en muchas funciones en vez de crearlo varias veces, despues uso la funcion onloand que como sabes su funcion principal es en si traer elementos como por ejemplo imagenes,frame al dom.

[mas informaciion de la funcion onloand aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

y  despues sencillamente dibujo el canva con la imagen con una sola linea y no creando otra funcion para eso(tu lo estas haciendo)

[mas informacion de como crear un elemento en canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

y por lo ultimo traigo la imagen del origen (yo la saque de google)

```js
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<html>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

en mi punto personal esta parte del codigo es innecesario:

```js
bannerHeader.imagen=new Image();
bannerHeader.imagen.src=bannerHeader.url;
bannerHeader.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarBanner());

function cargarBanner()
  {
    bannerHeader.cargaOK=true;
    dibujar()
  }
function dibujar()
{
  if(bannerHeader.cargaOK=true)
  {ctx.drawImage(bannerHeader.imagen,0,0)}
}
```

si la puedes hacer como yo lo hize